# Bootstrap Datepicker global _layout .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

(I'm working in .NET Core 3.1).

I have a bootstrap Datepicker into my _layout.

```
 <form class="form-inline ml-3">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                   <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" >
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

So, I wanna keep the value of ts datepicker every time a new view is loaded.
When a new view is loaded, _layout load again and datepicker back to blank. I need to keep the value that user pick regardless of the view where it is.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

there are tons of ways of doing this: [Check This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

what you need to decide is **storing this value on server side or client side?**

For server side approach. Here is the example

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(myDate, "11/04/2020");
```

just post date to the server side Controller/Action and store it into Session

Comment: Yes, I suppose there are many ways to do it. But I am looking for the best approach.

Said that, I don't want to store the date on the server side, because the value is already in the datepicker control. The goal is to pass the value of the datepicker to the same datepicker of ALL views that use the _layout where the datepicker is. (without repeating code in each view or each controller)